# Cамый простой сервер

Tags: сервер, python-3.x

Как сделать самый простой сервер, который можно запустить на линуксе, имея постояный ip на python?
Сервер должен уметь делать всего одну вещь - по запросу брать текст из файла и отправлять клиенту.
И как потом прикрепить его к url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте встроенный в питон веб-сервер. Запустить можно так:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

Запустится веб-сервер на 8000 порту, с текущей рабочей папкой.

Comment: 1- На большинстве Unix систем следует `python3` использовать, чтобы Python 3 версию запустить (автор упомянул линукс). 2- `http.server` не самая безопасная опция оставлять открытым для интернета 3- автор не упомянул http. И если мы хотим самый простой сервер, то можно прямо поверх socket сервер написать (аналог: `socat -u FILE:filename.txt TCP-LISTEN:8000,reuseaddr`).

Comment: А как к этому прикрепить адрес сайта? Чтобы можно было обращаться как yandex.ru/1.txt и файл отображался в браузере

Comment: @Юрий: `http://<ваш постоянный ip>:8000/имя.файла` в браузере (для http сервера в ответе). Или `nc  <ваш постоянный ip> 8000` в командной строке (для socat команды из моего комментария).

Comment: @jfs: python -m http.server 8000 включаю так на сервере, пишет serving on 0.0.0. ..., но не работает, почему так может быть?

Comment: *"не работает"* -- это не информативно: какие конкретно шаги выполняли, что ожидали получить и что вместо этого получается (сообщение об ошибке в консоле, в браузере -- копируйте как есть ввиде текста). Воспроизводится ли ошибка, если отключить файервол, антивирус? Добавьте информацию об используемых версиях (OS, python, браузер) и опубликуйте ввиде отдельного вопроса.

Comment: @jfs: Готово :)